# Codeigniter CSS, JS and images Not loading, assumes as directory probably

Tags: css, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-2

I'm pretty new to Codeigniter and have done all possible searches that I can do before reaching here.
I am using Code igniter 3x, my local CSS, Images and JS are not getting loaded into the Codeingiter application. I tried directly opening the CSS path but i believe Codeingiter assumes the path to be class/method/parameters! Below screenshot for reference.

[[image: When i try to browse it, am getting 404 error[2]]

[image: Below is my CSS Location]

Following is my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|logo\.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.
Anything that needs to be changed?

Comment: Place your assets folder outside of the application folder, place it in root folder.after that you can access it

Comment: Thanks a million, it worked :)  you literally saved me!

Comment: hey @harry  buddy all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Bhavesh Parab over comment, pleacing the asset folder at root fixed the issue.